# Where can I ask a question about why large-scale encoding choices were made?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to know something about why certain operating system makers chose `CR` vs `LF` vs `CRLF` in the present, particularly the usage of `CRLF` in Windows. Where would be the best place to ask this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History

Comment: @Mat thank you, that's quite informative. However, it does not cover my curiosity on the subject, since I am more interested in the "present" part of "past and present".